# Android CAB - can I start Support Action Mode in a DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-actionmode

CAB works fine in an AppCompatActivity.

Can I use it also in an DialogFragment (v4)? If so, what should I use as the context to start the action mode? The next statement does not work:

```
((AppCompatActivity) MainActivity.myActivity).startSupportActionMode( mcListener);
```

I know that the code is already in a Dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting the action mode on the current activity shows the action bar behind the dialog, so it is inaccessible without dismissing it.
After several trials to avoid this, I've had a look at the [source code of `AppCompatActivity`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.java), and managed to find a solution (what worked for me):

1. Created a field,

   ```
   private AppCompatDelegate delegate;
   ```
2. overrode `onStart` like this:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onStart () {
     super.onStart();

     Dialog dialog = getDialog();
     if (dialog != null) delegate = AppCompatDelegate.create(dialog, this);
   }
   ```
3. and created an action mode starter method

   ```
   @Nullable
   public ActionMode startSupportActionMode (ActionMode.Callback callback) {
     if (delegate != null) return delegate.startSupportActionMode(callback);
     return null;
   }
   ```

It can also work overriding `onCreateDialog` and create the delegate there, but from the source of `DialogFragment` the `getDialog` method supposed to return the same (current) dialog instance on `onStart` too, so it is ok creating the delegate there.

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer that works for all API levels:

```
Dialog dialog;
ActionMode.Callback actionMode;

Window window = dialog.getWindow();
View toplevel = window.getDecorView();
if (toplevel == null) { return; }

toplevel.startActionMode (actionMode);
```

Inspired by an answer created by MandisaW.

Comment: this seems to work great for api level `11+`, but as `startActionMode` was added to `View` in `11` it will fail for levels below that.

Comment: ...so I am still looking for a way to `startSupportActionMode` from my DialogFragment for older apis. I can use `((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).startSupportActionMode` but the CAB is appearing behind the dialog (and is inaccessible until the dialog is closed).